# Adding extra storage space to Dell PowerEdge 2900 SQL server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, sql-server, raid, scsi

Can a 300GB 15K RPM SAS (Serial Attached SCSI) Hard Drive work/be configured if i put it in an extra slot on a server that uses a DELL PERC 6/i Integrated RAID Controller?

Comment: What is the config presently? RAID level, existing drive size/speed/interface?

Comment: Raid 5, all other exisiting drives are 146gb sas 15k

Comment: Are you wanting to add this 300GB disk to the existing RAID5 array? If so, this can be done via DOMSA, but only 146GB of the new drive will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it can.

if you need to expand the existing array, use the reconfigure option in OMSA, otherwise, simply add another raid array of the raid-0 type with a single disk in.

Answer (score 0):

A general, non-specific question gets a general, non-specific answer: Yes.